# What's up with the "System Use" thing in PS Vita's Content Manager?

Tags: ps-vita

On one of my PlayStation Vita SD cards, I noticed something in Content Manager:

There is an **Other** section. This section has two parts-*System Use* and *Download Use*.

While *Download Use* is only taking up 128KB, this "*System Use*" is taking up 2532MB (~2.5GB).

This makes me really mad, seeing as this SD card is only 8GB, and I need to fit *Hatsune Miku Project DIVA f* on here (if it's even possible), along with all my music. At the moment, I only have about 69 songs (365MB) taking up any crucial space (referring to how I plan to delete anything else taking up space), but this list ***WILL*** grow in the future, and I'd like to have the space for then.

So, with all this being said, what even *is* the "System Use" thing, and how do I stop it from taking up space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"System Use" could refer to firmware updates and system software, updates / patches to system applications, or temporary or other system related data (e.g. cached information, system files etc). You can't clear / flush this data directly.

However, you can try using the Safe Mode to "Rebuild the Database" to see if it can clear up some of the space.

To activate Safe Mode, press "R" button + PS button + Power button while the console is turned off. Once in Safe Mode, use Option 2 "Rebuild Database".

Comment: Thanks. I actually ended up formatting my SD card after backing up data, and when you back it up, it acts as if it is going to back up that "System Use" stuff, too (and _kinda_ does), but, in the end, it's not on there when you restore it. Hahaha. It's kinda strange. But I used the Safe Mode thing you told me to update my system, because I put it in Safe Mode to test it out and decided to click on that.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently find out that most of my system use were unfinished/failed PKGj downloads and PSP/Adrenaline games, hope this will help. Sorry, too late?